# How do I denoize a microscopic image?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, image-recognition, computer-vision

I'm working in a computer vision project, where the goal is to detect some specific parasites, but now that I have the images, I noticed that they have a watermark that specifies the microscope graduation.
I have some ideas of how to remove this noise, like detecting the numbers and replace for the most common background or split the image but if I split the image I'll lose information.

But I would like to hear some recommendations and guidelines of experts.

I added an example image below.

[image]

Comment: What are your ideas? You should add in the question. The general method for denoising images is by the use of Denoising Autoencoder.

Comment: it would make more sense to just crop the image so that the label is removed. why don't you do that instead?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Yes but this is one optimal case, some labels are in different places